# nuSOAP binding operation input/output name missing

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I am using PHP and nuSoap. I need to add name parameters to binding input/output parameters. Any clues?

I have this code:

```
<binding name="serviceBinding" type="tns:servicePortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="ImportOrders">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:service#ImportOrders" style="document"/>
<input>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:service"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:service"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
```

I need to make it look like this (note name="ImportOrders*" in both input/output tags)

```
<binding name="serviceBinding" type="tns:servicePortType">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="ImportOrders">
<soap:operation soapAction="urn:service#ImportOrders" style="document"/>
<input name="ImportOrdersRequestType">
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:service"/>
</input>
<output name="ImportOrdersResponseType">
<soap:body use="literal" namespace="urn:service"/>
</output>
</operation>
</binding>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do so is to hard-code NuSoap plugin, nusoap.php file.